# Eigenvalues of a linear transformation of $M_{22}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

My question regards this problem:

> Let $T\colon M_{22} \to M_{22}$ be defined by 
>   $$T\left(
> \begin{bmatrix}
>   a & b \\
>   c & d 
> \end{bmatrix}
> \right)=
> \begin{bmatrix}
>     2c & a+c \\
>   b-2c & d
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$
>   (a) Find the eigenvalues of $T$.
>   (b) Find bases for the eigenspaces of $T$.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBDPX.png

I have already tried finding the determinant of the $ \lambda I -[T]$ matrix, getting the result:

$(\lambda -2c)(\lambda -d) - (2c-b)(-a-c) = \lambda^2 - d\lambda-2c\lambda+2cd+2ac+2c^2-ab-bc$

I am lost at this point, I don't see how I can factor this in a way that makes the eigenvalues clear. Any advice?

Comment: Collect terms by powers of $\lambda$ to get something like $A \lambda^2 + B \lambda + C$ and use the quadratic formula.

Comment: Are you sure there is no more elegant way than that? It just seems like it should be much simpler.

Comment: After looking at the image you posted (which you should type into the question): $T$ is a linear map of *matrices*, so the matrix in the problem is *not* the matrix of $T$; it tells you how $T$ transforms the single matrix $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$. Hence $\det(\lambda I - M)$, where $M$ is the array in the problem, does not give eigenvalues of $T$.

Comment: The linear map is a linear transformation between four dimensional spaces, the matrix of the linear map is a $4\times 4$ matrix. You have to calculate the eigenvalues of the latter matrix, the characteristic polynomial of that matrix is of degree 4 which yields 4 eigenvalues. Your approach is completely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

An ordered basis of $M_{22}$ is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}, \quad \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}, \quad \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}, \quad \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then the matrix of $T$ with respect to this basis is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Do you see why? Can you compute the eigenvalues from here?

Comment: Yes I can see that now, I clearly misunderstood the problem. Thank you for the clarification.